# NginX not taking ETag into account

Tags: php, symfony, caching, nginx

I enabled caching on NginX (using fastCGI).

My dynamic pages are not changing very often and I would like them to be stored in the NginX cache as long as they haven't changed (I know, I could create static pages instead... let say that they are still "dynamic" for historical reasons).

When my backend server (Symfony 2) is generating the page it is adding the ETAG + max-age parameters to the response header.

I would like the browser to keep the page in its cache for a certain amount of time. Once this time is expired I want the browser to send a "If-None-Match" HTTP HEAD with the provided ETAG.

If the page is still present in the frontend cache I want NginX to send a 304 Not Modified response.

If the page is not present anymore (I purged it manually if changed) I want NginX to forward the request to the backend server that sends back the HTTP 200 response.

**Without fastCGI** cache I can see the etag parameter is present in the response header (debug panel of firefox). But each time I reload the page I see a HTTP 200 response instead of a HTTP 304 response.

**With fastCGI** cache the ETag purely disappears from the initial HTTP 200 reponse. And each reload of the page leads to a HTTP 200 reponse (although X-Fastcgi-Cache parameter tells me this is a HIT)

***My questions***:

Why the browser is sending a GET request instead of a HEAD one although ETag exists?

Why ETag disappears from the response when I enable fastCGI cache on NginX?

I'm quite new to caching so I may be missing something big... .

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After investigation, the reason for these problems is that Firefox sets the ETag as being "weak" when the page is received in compressed format. It does this by adding an extra "W/" before the ETag string.

This leads symfony to not recognize the ETag as being the same as the one previously sent and hence the HTTP 200 response instead of HTTP 304.

The reason behind this extra weak info seems to be that when the ETag is computed before the data is compressed it could lead to ETag value collision and hence to page stuck in cache whereas it should be renewed. To prevent this Firefox (as well as NginX for information) adds the weak(ness) info.

Hope this can help someone with same problem... .

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for making fastcgi cache work together with etag?